# AWS localstack SES unable to connect to endpoint

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-ses, localstack

I want to use awslocal/localstack to mock out the endpoint/etc for my lambda function that sends an email using AWS ses/boto3.  i have used localstack for creating queues and SNS messages but not for aws ses. Normally for the queues i would write something in my awslocal sqs create-queue and etc... in my `localstack.sh`

I can't for the life of me figure out what I would need to create for SES using awslocal. i know my current issue is aws ses specific and probably related to localstack.sh because i can connect to create a queue.

I want to:

test locally and when I call `boto3.client.send_message` I want it to connect to my localhost port so I can receive the email sent successfully

I tried:

```
awslocal ses --endpoint-url="http://localhost:4579/"
```

did not work

any ideas?